# How to change Joomla article link?

Tags: joomla-3.x

By default Joomla is showing the linked articles in content to the main page. How can I change it to some where else?

Example:

OLD: http://localhost/newjoomla/index.php/2-uncategorised

NEW: http://localhost/newjoomla/index.php/menu-2/2-uncategorised

Comment: srsly, you put http://localhost/newjoomla/index.php/menu-2/2-uncategorised in your question? Try with C://MyDocuments/path/to/file next time, maybe that'll help.

Answer (score 1):

If you wanted to add the "menu-2/" to the path then make a menu item and then move the article menu item to have this as the "parent" it's a drop down menu on the left when editing the menu item. You can put menu items inside others for several levels.

You would also get some auto creation of url paths if you had articles in categories and added a menu item of Category Blog or Category List type, as this will make a page listing all articles, and the link will include category in the path, if not added manually in the first way.

Answer (score 0):

Create a menu item to the category of the article with the alias menu-2.

Answer (score -1):

Did you try change Menu item link?

Menu >> item link with "star"

This is your Home page set.

Comment: i just want this article after click dont show in my home page ! for example go to menu-2/contents not in home page contents

Comment: So just to change the link? Joomla never opens article on home page - they are opened on article page.

Comment: They are open in contents at home page , right?

Comment: He asks to change the path not place the story on the homepage.